# Replacing ASP.NET Ajax controls with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a solution that uses [Accordian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Widgets) and tab controls, amongst others.
Is it worth swapping these out and use the jQuery controls instead?

What are the benefits? Is it best practice to load one tab at a time with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make this swap in some test on my projects, from ASP.NET Ajax controls to jQuery controls, and my only issues was the UpdatePanel's.

ASP.NET take care the UpdatePanel messages (when you make asynchronous calls), but if you going to change it with jQuery you need to take care this updates by yourself - if you use UpdatePanel.

**Update.**
I agree with the comments for the UpdatePanel. I was working on a project, that had already many upadtePanels, and we just started to change some things to see what and how. If you build it up from the beginning I agree that it's better to avoid UpdatePanel, and do it with jQuery.

Comment: If you have to use an UpdatePanel in order to use the JQuery controls then I would say that was a minus.

Comment: The main reason I would like to switch is to avoid update panel. I was wondering what the performance improvement would be if jquery controls where used over ajax .net server controls such as the tab panel

Answer (score 3):

There are obviously benefits to using both, but in my experience if you are using ASP.NET then you are going to find the (I'm assuming you meant Ajax Control Toolkit) the ASP.NET controls better if you have a requirement for data-binding or have a high tendency to utilise your server execution time a lot.

IMO if the current controls meet your requirements then there isn't a breaking reason to switch to the jQuery controls, some ASP.NET server controls that provide Ajax functionality can be quite heavy-weight and cumbersome, but I've found controls like the Accordion to fit my needs perfectly, and wouldn't see a need to switch unless it wasn't flexible enough.